# Error trying to incorporate admob in my android application

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, admob

I'm trying to add admob into my app but i'm not having much luck.

I'm following the examples in the tutorial and using the XML method to create the banner. Everything seems to work fine and compile without error except for 1 part... (when I try to declare the activity in the manifest.)

Here is the entry i'm attempting:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

and here is the error i'm getting:

> error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value
>   'keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize').

In addition to this, if I attempt a clean and build with this entry present in the manifest, the R.file disappears and won't come back. I'm puzzled. I'm not very knowledgeable yet but i'm wondering if this error has something to do with an outdated syntax. The entry is copied word for word, but eclipse seems to be saying it doesn't know how to read it? Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The newest AdMob jar requires being build against the 13 SDK.  I added this to the manifest

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:maxSdkVersion="13"
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="13" />
```

You'll get a warning in the manifest that the minSdkVersion is less than the targetSdkVersion, but I haven't seen that cause any issues.

You also need to change the line in default.properties or project.properties to

```
target=android-13
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok that got me somewhere, the error on the activity is gone, but now i'm getting an error that says "cannot resolve target android-13" and now in the main src file all the imports that begin with android. say "cannot be resolved"

Comment: You probably need to update your android sdk to (at a minimum) sdk level 13, which is 3.2

Comment: Thanks yeah I looked in the properties and for some reason all the api's unchecked themselves, and my highest api is 8, so I guess that's the problem

Comment: Great answer mate, can't believe the high point minimum that these ads require. even my latest handset is no where near!